# How to cycle through an array to find a button with a certain ID in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm making a project where I'm in a modal and want the user to change pen size.
I have the ID for every pen size, but I thought of making an array, loop through it, match with an ID and then from that ID give a lineWidth. But it turned out to be a bit difficult.

Here is my code, the thought behind this is to have four different sizes - each connected to each button.

**JS:**

```
let penModal = document.getElementById("pennstorlek--modal");
let penClose = document.getElementsByClassName("pennstorlek__close")[0];

let penSizeButton = document.querySelector(".width");
penSizeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  penModal.style.display ="block";

  let penButtonSmall = document.getElementById("pennstorlek--liten");
  let penButtonMed = document.getElementById("pennstorlek--mellan");
  let penButtonLg = document.getElementById("pennstorlek--stor");
  let penButtonGig = document.getElementById("pennstorlek--gigant");

  let pennButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".pennstorlek--button");


  if (toolDrawing.lineWidth === 5){
    toolDrawing.lineWidth = 10;
  }
  else {
    toolDrawing.lineWidth = 5;
  }
})

penClose.addEventListener("click", () =>{
  penModal.style.display ="none";
})
```

Comment: what have you tried so far for looping? I do not see any code of the loop being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pushing penButtonSmall, penButtonMid, penButtonLg and penButtonGig into an array and then for loop through them using the .id property.
Something like this:

```
const sizes = [];
sizes.push(penButtonSmall);
//same for other 3 options.
for (i=0; i<4; i++)
{
 var x = sizes[i];
 if(x.id == "the_id_you_want")
 {//do something;
   }
}
```